# How can I create an object and/or properties on the fly in VB 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an object and/or properties on the fly...  Is this possible?

```
CLIENT_INFO
  NAME
    F_NAME (= "LoriBeth")
    L_NAME (= "Johnson")
  ADDRESS
    ADDY1 (= "123 MyStreet")
    ETC (= "Etc")
```

Where:

```
Dim objCreated as Object
Dim objName AS String = "CLIENT_INFO"
Dim 1stProp as String = "NAME"
etc...

objCreated = makeObject(objName, objProp1, etc...)

Function makeObject(byval objName as String, byval objProp1 as String, etc...)
  Class &objName
    Property &objProp1
    End Property
  End Class

  Return &objName
End Function
```

(I used the VFP way to replace vars with their values at runtime)

to end up with an object that is addressable like:

CLIENT_INFO.NAME.F_NAME = "LoriBeth"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single property typed as a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` to accomplish your expando- functionality.

But this whole thing seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hans, That is cool, good to know, but doesn't allow me to do what I first posted.  Even something like this would be more helpful:

```
Option Strict Off 
Imports System.Dynamic  
Module Module1     
   Sub Main()         
      Dim OldBag As Object = New ExpandoObject         
      OldBag.Name = "Hans"         
      OldBag.Age = 21         
      OldBag.NewName = "NewBag"
      Console.WriteLine(NewBag.Name)         
      Console.WriteLine(NewBag.Age)
   End Sub 
End Module
```